# Netezza nzload error: Day is zero

Tags: csv, netezza

I am using NZLOAD to load a massive .csv file into a netezza machine.  This .csv is a 30GB extract from an older database, so updating the formats is a challenge.

I have a field in the database that is causing problems.  The field represents the date that a customer performed some action.  Because most customers have not performed the action, they have null values.  NULL values for this field default to "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

The following error (not surprisingly) results:

```
1: 2(222) [22, TIMESTAMP] day is zero, ""0000-00-00"[ ]
```

Do you have any suggestions for working around this error?

Comment: Can you provide the nzload command options you are using, and also show us what a line of data with the NULL for the timestamp looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a table where the `datatype` of the field in question is `varchar(30)`
2. `nzload` to the new table
3. Insert into the table the existing table with a case statement:

`Select cast(case when textfield = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then null 
                  else textfield end
         as timestamp) 
 from new table`